# How to move checkmark through the cheboxlist?

Tags: javascript, checkbox

So i have checkboxlist

```
<input type="checkbox" name="colorc" value="black" />Black<br/><br>
<input type="checkbox" name="colorc" value="brown" />Brown<br/><br>
<input type="checkbox" name="colorc" value="white" />White<br/><br>
<input type="button" id="btnClick" value="Color Change"></button>
```

and when i press button, checkmark moves to next checkbox, the same i want if we have two checkmarks, but without using JQuery, clear JS. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess this would do:

```
document.getElementById("btnClick").onclick = function(){    
    var checkBoxes = document.getElementsByName("colorc");
    var checked = checkBoxes[checkBoxes.length - 1].checked;

    for(var i = checkBoxes.length-1; i > 0; --i){        
        checkBoxes[i].checked = checkBoxes[i-1].checked;
    }

    checkBoxes[0].checked = checked;
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/t231c0ga/1/

Answer (score 0):

The current checked input can be selected as:

```
input[name=colorc]:checked
```

The next input can be gotten using the [general sibling selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_selectors) (~):

```
input[name=colorc]:checked ~ input[name=colorc]
```

Change your inputs from checkboxes to radio buttons, and use this code.  If there's no *next* input, it defaults to the first input:

```js
document.getElementById('btnClick')
  .addEventListener('click',function() {
    var next= 
          document.querySelector(
            'input[name=colorc]:checked ~ input[name=colorc]'
          ) || 
          document.querySelector('input[name=colorc]');
    
    next.checked= true;
  });
```

```html
<input type="radio" name="colorc" value="black" checked/>Black<br/><br>
<input type="radio" name="colorc" value="brown" />Brown<br/><br>
<input type="radio" name="colorc" value="white" />White<br/><br>
<input type="button" id="btnClick" value="Color Change"></button>
```